# В чем проблема и почему не работает на github-pages?

Tags: java, spring, github, github-pages

Ссылка на мой [репозиторий GitHub](https://github.com/userJ3/userJ3.github.io)

Как работает у меня:
[image: как работает у меня]
 Как работает в github-pages:
[image: Как работает в github-pages]
 Как работает в github-pages 2:
[image: Как работает в github-pages 2]

Ссылка на видео по которому делал - [ссылка](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaVGIYxE23c&list=PLAma_mKffTOR5o0WNHnY0mTjKxnCgSXrZ&index=23)

В чем проблема? Как сделать так, чтобы работало нормально?

Comment: А почему вы решили, что оно вообще должно работать на github-pages?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю GitHub Pages работает исключительно как сервис для публикации html/css/js контента, а не как полноценный сервер с backend, для этого нам к сожалению нужно поднимать собственный или арендованный сервер.